# Is there a noncommutative ring with prime characteristic?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory

Is there a noncommutative ring with prime characteristic?

My first answer is “no”, because $(R, +)$ is an abelian group, and I think that the characteristic is related to (or the same as) the order of the group $(R, +)$, i.e., every ring with prime characteristic is either $\mathbb{Z}_p$ or something related to $\mathbb{Z}_p$. But I'm not able to prove it, or give a counterexample.

Where am I wrong?

Comment: How about $\mathbb{F}_p\langle x,y \rangle$, i.e. the free algebra of (non-commuting) words in variables $x$ and $y$, over the field $\mathbb{F}_p$?

Comment: $M_2(\Bbb{F}_p)$ the $2\times 2$ matrices with entries in $\Bbb{F}_p$. All its elements satisfy $ \underbrace{A+\ldots +A}_p = 0$ so it has characteristic $p$.

Comment: Thanks, matrix works for me, I'm not in free-algebra yet hehe

Comment: In your (non-)proof you mix up rings with groups.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take any non-abelian group $G$ and consider the group ring $\mathbb{F}_p[G]$ ($p$ prime).

Comment: Or indeed any noncommutative monoid, which recovers the free algebra example from the comments. Nice answer!

Comment: Yes and thanks Izaak!

Answer (score 1):

> I think that the characteristic is related to (or the same as) the order of the group $(,+)$

Not really unless $R$ is finite, when by Lagrange's theorem the maximum order of an element must divide $|R|$. $|R|$ can easily be infinite while having positive characteristic, for example.  The connection is not strong.

> i.e., every ring with prime characteristic is either $ℤ_$ or something related to $ℤ_.$

The only relationship is that a ring (with identity) with characteristic $p$ contains a copy of $\mathbb Z_p$. This is true for $p$ not prime as well.  It is just the subring generated by the identity $1$.

Even when $R$ is finite and has positive characteristic, it is completely possible for it to be noncommutative: a small example would be the upper triangular matrices over the field of two elements. It has eight elements, is noncommutative, and characteristic $2$.

Answer (score 1):

$M_2(\mathbb{F}_p).\phantom{--------}$